# Count average radio button input values, jQuery

Tags: jquery, input

I'm using rather simple function to count average value of multiple radio button inputs. It does work, it seems, but the value counted is not correct.

```js
$("#submit_button").click(function() {
  var total = 0,
    valid_labels = 0,
    average;

  $('.input_value').each(function() {
    var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
      valid_labels += 1;
      total += val;
    }
  });

  $('.avg_score').val(total / valid_labels);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=1>1</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=2>2</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=3>3</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=4>4</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=5>5</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=6>6</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=7>7</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=1>1</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=2>2</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=3>3</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=4>4</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=5>5</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=6>6</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=7>7</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="text" class="avg_score" name="avg_score" width="30" height="50" value="">avg. score</label>

<section id="submit">
  <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit_button" value="Send">
</section>
```

That's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/efgxLgw3/

Comment: try just add `:checked` to your foreach, like this https://jsfiddle.net/efgxLgw3/1/

Comment: I dont understand....why people keep posting answers when it is already resolved with comment!

Comment: This is great and so obvious, im ashamed! Thanks. Can't mark your answer as correct, since it was given in a comment. Or can i ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because you're looping through all the radios, not just the one which was `:checked`. To fix that you can just add `:checked` to your selector.

However, you could amend the logic by using `reduce()`, like this:

```js
$("#submit_button").click(function() {
  var $checked = $('.input_value:checked');
  var total = $checked.map(function() {
    return parseInt(this.value, 10);
  }).get().reduce(function(a, b) { 
    return a + b;
  });
  
  $('.avg_score').val(total / $checked.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=1>1</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=2>2</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=3>3</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=4>4</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=5>5</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=6>6</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=7>7</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=1>1</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=2>2</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=3>3</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=4>4</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=5>5</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=6>6</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=7>7</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="text" class="avg_score" name="avg_score" width="30" height="50" value="">avg. score</label>

<section id="submit">
  <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit_button" value="Send">
</section>
```

Comment: Would like to know why, I can't see any problem with your answer

Comment: To be honest, I could see why - this uses two loops. I added it as an alternative to `each()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a little shorter one, here you go:

```js
$("#submit_button").click(function() {
  var total = 0, valid_labels = $('.input_value:checked').length;
    
  for(var i = 0; i < valid_labels; i++){
    total += parseInt($('.input_value:checked')[i].value);
  }

  $('.avg_score').val(total / valid_labels);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=1>1</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=2>2</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=3>3</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=4>4</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=5>5</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=6>6</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q7" value=7>7</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=1>1</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=2>2</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=3>3</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=4>4</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=5>5</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=6>6</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="input_value" name="q8" value=7>7</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="text" class="avg_score" name="avg_score" width="30" height="50" value="">avg. score</label>

<section id="submit">
  <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit_button" value="Send">
</section>
```